# My .Apk is work in simulator but not working in Android mobile?

Tags: android, layout

Hay 
geek guys ... really i am facing this type problem first time..

My app is working good in simulator but not working in Galaxy 5.. 
i am getting **Package Parsing** error ..i don't know what this error i am getting

help me to solve out ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: How to you install your apk on the device? Try to run it from eclipse (if you use eclipse for developing)

Comment: from bin/myapp.apk file i am installing in mobile.. i have tested in eclipse its working good

Comment: guys i found that if your sdk version not matching than thia may occur ? so what you think about that ?

Comment: @rekaszeru: if I could downvote your comment, I would do that. You didn't read the question and just wrote the standard "not enough information" phrase. Read carefully next time!

Comment: @WarrenFaith .. Thanks for protect spamming

Comment: @WarrenFaith, maybe you should read my comment more carefully. I asked for a debug session on the device (the problem occures on the device, when running it). Maybe what I'm asking makes sense only to me, or I really have misunderstood the situation / problem described above. If so, i'm sorry.

Comment: @rekaszeru: The problem starts before running the app, because the app is not installable on the device, so a debug session isn't possible.

Comment: @WarrenFaith, thanks for clearing that up, it wasn't obvious for me, that's why i asked for the 'spam-like' stack trace. Sorry for my mistake, i'll remove my comment.

Comment: @rekaszeru.. hmmm... its ok now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is issue caused to variation SDK versions.

I think Galaxy 5 runs OS 2.1 and your sdk target your project might be 2.2 or above..

Try setting the `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />` in your manifest file of the project.

Comment: one more think i got.. if you will change your .apk file name than also problem occur

Answer (score 0):

As Jana said. this may be sdk version problem. But what i think is you
have not signed your app. Please check this  http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html